# g++ does not recognize include directory

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, dlib

RESOLVED: I'm not entirely sure why and how but when I changed from -I~/dlib-18.18 to -I../dlib-18.18 then it works.

I'm trying to write a makefile that compiles a program using the dlib library. I have downloaded and install the library in the roots directory.

The header of the .cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "dlib/optimization.h"
#include <iostream>
```

dlib folder is included within dlib-18.18 and optimization.h is indeed within the dlib folder.

Below is my makefile (or part of it). I have included the relevant directory in CFLAGS. However, during compilation, g++ says that it cannot find optimization.h (No such file or directory)

```
EXUCUTABLE = graph

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -I. -I/usr/include/ -I~/dlib-18.18
FLAGS = -g -O -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -pedantic

############### Rules ###############

all: ${EXUCUTABLE}

clean:
    rm -f ${EXUCUTABLE} *.o
## Compile step (.cpp files -> .o files)

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${FLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} -c $< 

graph: graph.o
    ${CXX} ${FLAGS} $^ -o $@
```

[Output for terminal make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szdjf.png)

[The /dlib-18.18/dlib folder when accessed from the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1cT6.png)

Comment: You mention `.cpp` but have the rule `%.o: %.c`. Shouldn't this be `%.o: %.c %.cpp` or set `CXXFLAGS`?

Comment: So the path to the header is `/dlib-18.18/dlib/optimization.h`? That seems weird on two counts, likely wrong on one of them. The possibly wrong one is that you'd have a library's headers located in a special folder in root. Are you sure you didn't mean `/usr/include/dlib-18.18`, `./dlib-18.18`, or something? Second, are the headers stored in a `dlib` subdirectory of `dlib-18.18`, or did you mean `#include "dlib-18.18/optimization.h"`?

Answer (score 0):

You got your pattern wrong: `%.o: %.c` denotes that the rule is about compiling `.c` files (*not* `.cpp` files).

As a result, this rule doesn't apply and GNU Make falls back to its own set of default rules for compiling your C++ code.

Try this instead (assuming you're consistent with dlib, and you're using the `.cpp` extension for your C++ files):

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -I. -I/usr/include/ -I~/dlib-18.18
FLAGS = -g -O -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wfatal-errors -std=c++11 -pedantic

# To get *any* .o file, compile its .cpp file with the following rule.
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Now run `make -B` and watch the compiler output for `-I~/dlib-18.18` options on the g++ command lines.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, after changing .c to .cpp I'm still getting the same error (directory/file not found)

Comment: Can you edit your question and copy/paste the output of `make` ?

Comment: The output of make is not very helpful, it just yells that the file cannot be found

Comment: Ok, I see `-I~/dlib-18.18`, which means g++ is looking for dlib in your home directory, not in the root directory as you said earlier.  Set that `-I` path to wherever your library is installed, and it should be fine.

Comment: Ok, I just realized you're trying to compile `graph.cpp` with `gcc` instead of `g++`.  You'll have to correct that too. (so yes, the output is helpful :-)

Comment: Sorry if I was being confusing for saying "root" directory but I meant "home" directory. Given that, typing ~/dlib-18.18 on the terminal is a legit directory path and includes the dlib folder

Comment: All right, I've updated my initial response accordingly.  That g++ line should read: `g++ -I. -I~/dlib-18.18 -o graph.o -c graph.cpp` (you can get rid of `-I/usr/include`, it will be included in the search paths anyway).

Comment: oops, I changed my makefile but did not update my question. But even with g++ I still got the same error